# JHipster Angular frontend - Cannot find name 'AuthServerProvider'

Tags: angular, jhipster

I manage to make to fix the issues with the backend generated by JHipster but now I have an error for the Angular app generated.

The app was generated using the following command line:

`jhipster --skip-server --db MySQL --auth JWT`

I've try twice and I get the same error:
[image]

Here are my angular env details:

[image]

Comment: Did you `import AuthServiceProvider` in the `login.service.ts`?

Comment: No. I was thinking on this but there is no file or implementation for AuthServiceProvider

Comment: It should be in src/main/webapp/app/core/auth/auth-jwt.service.ts like https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/webapp/app/core/auth/auth-jwt.service.ts  If it's not available then something went wrong

Comment: @GaëlMarziou that was the issue. I have manually created the file and imported and now is all good. Also it was needed to replace the login with the one from the repo(I have the latest version of jhipster)